# What's wrong with this regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying the following code on Java:

```
String test = "http://asda.aasd.sd.google.com/asdasdawrqwfqwfqwfqwf";
String regex = "[http://]{0,1}([a-zA-Z]*.)*\\.google\\.com/[-a-zA-Z/_.?&=]*";
System.out.println(test.matches(regex));
```

It does work for several minutes (after that I killed the VM) with no result.
Can anyone help me?

BTW: What will you recommend me to do to speed up weblink-testng regexes in future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[http://]` is a character class, meaning any *one* of those characters from the set.

Just leave those particular square brackets off if it *must* start with `http://`. If it's optional, you can use `(http://)?`.

One obvious problem is that you're looking for the sequence `([a-zA-Z]+.)*\\.google` - this will do a *lot* of backtracking due to that naked `.` which means "any character" rather than the literal period that you wanted.

But even if you replace it with what you *meant*, `([a-zA-Z]+\\.)*\\.google`, you still have a problem - this will then require two `.` characters immediately before `google`. You should instead try:

```
String regex = "(http://)?([a-zA-Z]+\\.)*google\\.com/[-a-zA-Z/_.?&=]*";
```

That returns immediately for me with a `true` match.

Keep in mind that this currently requires the `/` at the end of `google.com`. If that's a problem, it's a minor fix, but I've left it there since you had it in your original regex.

Comment: you can use (i?)[a-z] instead of [a-zA-Z], it ignores the case

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to match the scheme as a character class using square brackets. That means only zero or one of the characters from that set. You want a subpattern, with parentheses. You can also change `{0,1}` to just say `?`.

Also, you should remove the period just before `google\\.com` because you're already looking for a period in the subdomain subpattern of your regex. As cherouvim points out, you forgot to escape that period as well.

```
String regex = "(http://)?([a-zA-Z]+\\.)*google\\.com/[-a-zA-Z/_.?&=]*";
```

Comment: Even that change doesn't prevent Java from chugging away at the regex for a very long time.

Comment: Put a `+` after the first `*`.

Answer (score 3):

In the `([a-zA-Z]*.)` part you either need to escape the `.` (because right now it means "all characters") or remove it.

Comment: Strike! That's the mistake that caused the "infinite loop" behaviour. good catch! (verified your solution with ideone)

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the regular expression.

The first is easy, as was mentioned by others. You need to match "http://" as a subpattern, not as a character class. Change the brackets to parentheses.

The second problem causes the very poor performance. It's causing the regex to backtrack repeatedly, trying to match the pattern.

What you're trying to do is match zero or more subdomains, which are groups of letters followed by a dot. Since you want to match the dot explicitly, escape the dot. Also remove the dot in front of "google" so you can match "http://google.com/etc" (ie, no leading dot in front of google).

So your expression becomes:

```
String regex = "(http://){0,1}([a-zA-Z]+\\.)*google\\.com/[-a-zA-Z/_.?&=]*";
```

Running this regex on your example takes just a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you fix the `([a-zA-Z]*\\.)` you need to change `*` to `+` so the part becomes `([a-zA-Z]+\\.)`. Otherwise you'll be accepting `http://...google.com` and this is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

By grouping part before `google.com` I assume you are looking for part of URL host name. I think that rexep is powerful tool, but you can simply use [URL Java class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). There is `getHost()` method. Then you can check if host name ends with `google.com` and split it or use some simplier regexp with only host name.

```
URL url = new URL("http://asda.aasd.sd.google.com/asdasdawrqwfqwfqwfqwf");
String host = url.getHost();
if (host.endsWith("google.com"))
    {
    String [] parts = host.split("\\.");
    for (String s: parts)
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: It depends on whether there is network connectivity, and also on performance requirements.

Comment: I tested it without direct HTTP network connectivity (proxy with password), this URL doesn't work in browser, but I was able to use URL class. Can you give me some more info about URL class depending on network connectivity?

Comment: I've tested the perfomance with regex

    (http://)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.)*google((syndication)|(-analytics))?\\.com/[-a-zA-Z0-9/_.?&=]*

and patterns

google.com
google-analytics.com
googlesyndication.com

It takes 985 ms for regex to check 100 000 links, while URL takes 156 ms